# "error adding symbols: file format not recognized" while cross compiling with an extern library

Tags: gcc

When cross compiling with gcc-arm-none-aebi and some external libraries, I get the following error message: `cross/lib/libgsl.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized`
I have used the --target=arm-none-eabi and --prefix function while buiding the library.
For cross compiling I have used the following command:
`$HOME/arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c  -I/$HOME/arm -L/$HOME/arm/cross/lib -lgsl`

I have already tried to use another gcc version (the same like the one of gcc-arm-none-eabi), but didn't help.